# Compass version of CSS3 3D transform code

Tags: css, transform, compass-sass

Is there a [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) equivalent for the following CSS3 3D transform code?

```
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, -30deg);
-moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, -30deg);
```

Comment: I've never used Compass, but a quick Google returns this: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transform/

Answer (score 5):

two options:

```
@include rotate3d(0, 0, 0, -30deg);
```

or:

```
@include transform(rotate3d(0, 0, 0, -30deg));
```

The second is useful if you need to combine it with other transforms. It's all there in the [Compass Docs](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transform/).

Comment: In my experience, you'll need to use `@include` in place of `@mixin`. `@mixin` should be used when defining a mixin. OP needs to include an existing mixin (existing within compass). See: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#defining_a_mixin